# Is there a way to make portals for teleportation in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to make portals in Minecraft teleport to each other in SMP? I have hell mode off because it always spawns us in hell. I want to know if I can use portals to teleport from one location across the map to another.

Comment: This is related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/what-could-cause-a-minecraft-portal-to-not-work - although the questions themselves are not exact duplicates, the answer is the same to both.

Comment: This is related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11107/how-does-the-nether-work-in-minecraft-smp also, giving another of the same answer. Do we really need three of the same questions here?

Comment: Are you asking about portals to the Nether or portals between two different places in the "normal" world?

Comment: i want to know about using portals between two different places in the "normal" world

Comment: This question is obsolete, as Nether portals and the Nether now function correctly in SMP.

Comment: @KevinReid and why should it be obsolete?

Answer (score 8):

There are a few plugins available if you run the Bukkit mod.

[Here](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-nether-v1-1-super-simple-nether-portals-450.4447/)'s an example, though there are still bugs associated with the Nether in general.

There is a bit of a read [here](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/multiworld-nether-a-planet-full-of-creepers.3610/), but it is all pretty relevant.

Since the above is all pretty Nether-related, and you said you want portals in the same world, [check out this](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-stargate-v0-20-beta-the-bukkit-port-a-portal-plugin-b493jnks.3927/) as well.

Answer (score 6):

Portal functionality is not yet implemented in SMP. You can make the portal and light it, but stepping inside will do nothing.

It is unsure exactly how SMP portals will be implemented, but Notch has been [quoted](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/27923285752) saying that they will link different servers together, and he [confirms](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/29024952874) that they will be usable for fast-travel within a server. Common rumor also states that they will allow transportation between SMP servers and single-player worlds.

When you create a world in SMP, you can either create it as a normal world or a hell world. Once it has been created, it is not recommended that you switch between types, as [problems can occur](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11107/how-does-the-nether-work-in-minecraft-smp). Be sure to set `hellworld=true` or `hellworld=false` inside `server.properties` **before** allowing the server to run.

Answer (score -3):

Make a 100x100 frame out of cobblestone then fill it with wood and light it then go through it.